# ASP.net 4.0 WebService and public static class is this possible?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, static, asmx

It is giving the error below. It is not possible to use webservice class as static or i am doing wrong ?

[image]

Comment: Why would you need it to be a static class in the first place?

Comment: Why are you still using ASMX web services instead of WCF? ASMX is a legacy technology according to Microsoft.

Comment: You are probably being confused by examples you've seen of "Page Methods". These are pseudo web services created in ASPX code behind to serve the needs of a specific page. They must be static.

Comment: John Saunders what is wrong with this web service ? i am using asp.net web site. Can i still use wcf web service ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A static class cannot derive from another class. And no, a web service cannot be a static class as it has to derive from the `WebService` base class.

Comment: so it is not possible ? i see.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG, no, it is not possible and I don't see why would you need something like this to be possible.